# Is there a better way to iterate through this calculation?

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

Running this code produces the error message :

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. 
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I have 6 years' worth of competitor's results from a 1/2 marathon in one csv file.
The function `year_runners` aims to create a new column for each year with a difference in finishing time between each runner.
Is there a more efficient way of producing the same result?
Thanks in advance.

```
Pos  Gun_Time               Chip_Time              Name           Number     Category

1    1900-01-01 01:19:15    1900-01-01 01:19:14    Steve Hodges   324        Senior Male        
2    1900-01-01 01:19:35    1900-01-01 01:19:35    Theo Bately     92        Supervet Male
```

---

```
#calculating the time difference between each finisher in year and adding this result to into a new column called time_diff
def year_runners(year, x, y):
print('Event held in', year)
# x is the first number (position) for the runner of that year, 
# y is the last number (position) for that year e.g. 2016 event spans from df[246:534]
time_diff = 0
#
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    time_diff = df2015.loc[(x + 1),'Gun_Time'] - df2015.loc[(x),'Chip_Time'] 
# using Gun time as the start-time for all.
# using chip time as finishing time for each runner.
# work out time difference between the x-placed runner and the runner behind (x + 1)
    df2015.loc[x,'time_diff'] = time_diff #set the time_diff column to the value of time_diff for 
    #each row of x in the dataframe
    print("Runner",(x+1),"time, minus runner" , x,"=",time_diff)
    x += 1
    if x > y: 
        break
```

Hi everyone, this was solved using the shift technique.
[youtube.com/watch?v=nZzBj6n_abQ](http://youtube.com/watch?v=nZzBj6n_abQ)

df2015['shifted_Chip_Time'] = df2015['Chip_Time'].shift(1)

df2015['time_diff'] = df2015['Gun_Time'] - df2015['shifted_Chip_Time']

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and expected output.

Comment: Yes, use `shift` instead `of .loc((x+1),....`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Scott. I tried using the following but also got the following error message. Am I using shift correctly in this context? time_diff = df2015['Gun_Time'].shift(1) - df2015.loc[(x),'Chip_Time'] . This is the error I now get : TypeError: Could not operate Timestamp('1900-01-01 01:19:14') with block values descriptor '__sub__' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'float'